# Socket IO separate javascript listener

Tags: javascript, laravel, socket.io

I have the following code in my main layout html

```
var baseUrl = "{{ env('SOCKET_BASE_URL') }}";
var socket = io.connect(baseUrl + ':3000');
socket.on("message-channel:App\\Events\\BroadcastMessageToUser", function(message){
    // alert the user about the message
});
```

my problem is, sometimes when a message was emitted, and timely, the user to receive the message refreshed or clicked a link; the message will be missed by this listener.(the message will never be received but it was sent)

Now I thought that if it's possible to separate this listener so that even if the tab was refreshed or the user clicked a link, this listener will not be refreshed, it will still be connected to receive messages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect. Socket.io only *transmits* information, it doesn't *persist* it. In order to ensure that information is retained upon a new HTTP request, you need to store all messages in a database, the filesystem, or some other more permanent medium.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "separate the listener from the tab".  When a browser page is refreshed, all webSocket connections are closed and all state associated with that page is released.  You can't keep a webSocket/socket.io connection from that page open while the page is refreshed.

The socket.io methods that broadcast to all connected clients send only to all clients that are connected at that moment in time.  If you want clients that may connect a short time in the future to also get a particular message, then you will have to save that message and send it to those clients when they next connect.

Assuming your have some method of identifying each user's connection, you could keep track of when a user disconnects their socket.io connection and then if you see a connection event shortly thereafter, you could send them any messages that they would have missed while they were reconnecting.  You'd have to maintain some sort of list of recent messages, a list of recently disconnected clients and probably use some sort of event counter so you could know which events to send a newly reconnected client.